# Is there a web server or application level setting that indicates to the browser that the page has been modified?

Tags: asp.net

We have an issue where when we upgrade our ASP .NET web application, some customers still see the old pages (old code) instead of the new code.

Would like to know if there is a server or application level setting that indicates to the browser that the page has been modified and forces a download instead of loading from cache, without having to make any code change?

Thanks,

Sunil

Comment: You want to look at adding cache control headers to your server responses: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control.  This will force the browser to do a HEAD request on page load and only load the page from your origin server when it has changed.